# Routing undefined routes in laravel

Tags: laravel

So I have some routes and all that. But is there a way to to redirect a person that typed in a random URI to a specific "There is no such page" kind of view where the person could still use the menu and all that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of Laravel you're using but assuming it's a later version, you can do something like this:

In app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

This would basically check for a Page not Found scenario and render a 404 page. Depending on how you setup your 404 error view, you could allow the user to see the menu but also display a custom message that they've gone to the wrong place.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler for more information on error handling and aborting on specific HTTP errors as well as how to setup custom error views.

Answer (score 0):

The view in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` can be modified to show whatever you want. This is shown whenever a "Not Found (404)" error is thrown.